# Load Duration Curve Showing Inflection Points

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, seaborn

I am trying to plot a load duration curve in Python. I am starting with data in an XLSX file and want to create load duration curves of a cooling load data (x-axes as percentage of time and cumulative hours, respectively).

However, I want to include ranges of the load duration curve. To do so, I want to add vertically dashed lines at the intersection points of tangents through inflection points.

My solution is running, but the plots show horizontal red lines (which makes no sense at all to me since `axvlines` should give vertical lines). I believe there might be an issue with the proper identification of the inflection points. Here is my current result:

**Current Plot**
[image: 1]

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

**Load Duration Curve With Ranges - vertical lines at inflection points which can be obtained as intersection points of tangents through inflection points**
[image: 1]

My current code:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb
import numpy as np
import time
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter1d

# create dataframe from XLSX file
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, index_col='Zeitstempel', parse_dates=True, usecols=[0, 1])[3:35043]

# sort the DataFrame by the loads, in descending order of magnitude
df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['Kältelast'], ascending=False)

# Calculate the duration for which the system load is greater than or equal to each load
df_sorted['duration'] = df_sorted['Kältelast'].ge(df_sorted['Kältelast']).cumsum()

# convert timestamp to Unix timestamp format
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: int(time.mktime(x.timetuple())))

# Calculate the total duration of the data in minutes
total_duration = (df.index[-1] - df.index[0]) / 60
print(f'Total duration is {total_duration} minutes.')

# Calculate the percentage of time for which the system load is greater than or equal to each load
df_sorted['percentage'] = df_sorted['duration'] * 15 * 100 / total_duration

# calculate the cumulative hours for each load
df_sorted['cumulative_hours'] = (df_sorted['duration'] * 15) / 60

# apply Gaussian smoothing to 'Kältelast' column
sigma = 5.65  # adjust this to change the smoothing level
smoothed = gaussian_filter1d(df_sorted['Kältelast'], sigma)
df_sorted['Kältelast (geglättet)'] = smoothed

# add smoothed data as a new column in the dataframe
smoothed_d2 = np.gradient(np.gradient(smoothed)) 

# find inflection points
inflection_points = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(smoothed_d2)))[0]

df_sorted = df_sorted.reset_index()

# Load vs Percentage of time with inflection points
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
p1 = sb.lineplot(x="percentage", y="Kältelast", data=df_sorted, ax=ax1 )
p1 = sb.lineplot(x="percentage", y="Kältelast (geglättet)", data=df_sorted, ax=ax1, linestyle='--')

# Plot vertical lines at the inflection points
for index in inflection_points:
    x_value = df_sorted.loc[index, 'percentage']  # Get the percentage value of the inflection point
    ax1.axvline(x=x_value, color='r', linestyle='--')

plt.ylim(0, None)
plt.xlim(0, 100)
p1.set_title("Jahresdauerlinie", fontweight='bold')
p1.set_xlabel("Zeit in %")
p1.set_ylabel("Kältelast in kW")
plt.tick_params(axis='both')
plt.tight_layout()


# Load vs Cumulative hours with inflection points
fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
p2 = sb.lineplot(x="cumulative_hours", y="Kältelast", data=df_sorted, ax=ax2)
plt.ylim(0, None)
plt.xlim(0, None)
p2.set_title("Jahresdauerlinie", fontweight='bold')
p2.set_xlabel("Betriebsstunden in h")
p2.set_ylabel("Kältelast in kW")
plt.tick_params(axis='both')
plt.tight_layout()

# Plot vertical lines at the inflection points
for index in inflection_points:
    x_value = df_sorted.loc[index, 'cumulative_hours']  # Get the cumulative hours value of the inflection point
    ax2.axvline(x=x_value, color='r', linestyle='--')

plt.show()
```

A few lines of the data frame (Note that it holds four values per hour, i.e. every 15 minutes. Hence the calculation of `df_sorted['percentage']`):

```
                      Kältelast
Zeitstempel
2012-01-01 00:00:00  21.235797
2012-01-01 00:15:00  24.334678
2012-01-01 00:30:00  20.874288
2012-01-01 00:45:00  23.476754
2012-01-01 01:00:00  23.834566
...                         ...
2012-12-31 22:45:00   5.515756
2012-12-31 23:00:00   5.537896
2012-12-31 23:15:00   6.554896
2012-12-31 23:30:00   6.523645
2012-12-31 23:45:00   5.512456
```

Answer (score 0):

> My solution is running, but the plots show horizontal red lines (which makes no sense at all to me).

I believe you mean vertical lines. It's expected since you're calling `axvline()` for each inflection point X position. [See axvline doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html).

From the *good visual representation of what you are trying to achieve*, it seems like what you want to plot is the tangent lines for each inflection point based on the computed gradients. You'll need `ax.plot()` rather `ax.axvline()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Indeed, I am getting horizontal lines, even though `axvline()` should give vertical lines. I have a added a current plot output to show this.
I am firstly interested in getting vertically dashed lines at the inflection points - the tangent lines are a bonus if that works.